# Vue does not account for hidden text when calculating width

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vue/Vuetify app that sometimes displays a very long text string. When the string is especially long, I cut off the overflow using the CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` property. The ellipsis itself appears correctly, but it seems the full length of the text is being used when Vue or the browser calculates width for positioning other elements on the page.

I've posted an MCVE at https://codepen.io/anon8171/pen/rNxYELZ.

Expected behavior:
The green box is at the right side of the screen, aligned with all the rest of the content.

[image]

Actual behavior:
The green box is on a new line underneath the rest of the content. This is because the hidden part of the string is long enough to push into the box's space. I confirmed this by disabling `overflow: hidden` in my app and looking at the exact spot where the box wraps.

[image]

To see this yourself in the codepen, just change the length of the string that contains the word "long" over and over.

I have noticed that adding `max-width: 500px` (or any pixel value) to the `<span>` produces the desired behavior. Unfortunately, percentage values don't seem to work, and I don't want to use a fixed pixel width in production.

Is there some way to get just the visible part of the string used for width calculations?

Comment: Doesn't `col` parameter on the wrapper component work for you?

Comment: https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/QWyOXzx

Comment: I acknowledge your codepen appears to do what I asked, but the solution doesn't work in my actual app. Must have left something out of the MCVE that actually was relevant after all. Investigating now. Also when the window is resized down enough your solution has the green box overlapping the rightmost text (the "foo bar baz").

Comment: I know you said %s don't work, but have you tried vw?

Comment: No, I didn't know about vw, looks like that should work. The layout ended up changing enough that this exact problem became obsolete for me. I think the reason the pen worked but the actual app didn't was that I had extra margin on the elements. So, like, `<first-thing cols="8" /><second-thing cols="4" />` would be okay but `<first-thing cols="8" class="mx-5" /><second-thing cols="4" class="mx-3"/>` wouldn't. Using padding instead of margin might have helped.